# XML Node to String Conversion for Large Sized XML

Tags: java, android, xml, out-of-memory, xslt

Till now I was using **DOMSource** to transform the XML file into string, in my Android App.

**Here's my code** :

```
public  String convertElementToString (Node element) throws TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerFactoryConfigurationError
{
      Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
      transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

       //initialize StreamResult with File object to save to file
      StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
      DOMSource source = new DOMSource(element);

      try {
          transformer.transform(source, result);  
      } 
      catch (TransformerException e) {
          Log.e("CONVERT_ELEMENT_TO_STRING", "converting element to string failed. Aborting", e);
      }

      String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
      xmlString = xmlString.replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>", "");
      xmlString = xmlString.replace("\n", "");
      return xmlString; 
}
```

This **was working fine for small xml** files.

**But** for **large sized xml** this code started **throwing OutOfMemoryError**.

What may be the reason behind it and how to rectify this problem?

Comment: How large is the XML?

Comment: It may reach up to 10-15 MB.

Answer (score 1):

First off: if you just need the XML as a string, and aren't using the `Node` for anything else, you should use StAX ([Streaming API for XML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/index.html)) instead, as that has a much lower memory footprint. You'll find StAX in the `javax.xml.stream` package of the standard libraries.

One improvement to your current code would be to change the line

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
```

to

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
```

Since you're stripping newlines anyway at the end of the method, it's not very useful to request additional indentation in the output. It's a small thing, but might reduce your memory requirements a bit if there are a lot of tags (hence, newlines and whitespace for indentation) in your XML.

Comment: I know this is ancient, but I want to use StAX to get the XML as a string and I cannot find any examples anywhere.  Can you?  I have a Document and I want to output it as an XML string.  The only examples I can find are looping through and building up an object.

Comment: @hobbes_child If you already have a `Document`, there is no need to involve StAX. Just pass the `Document` instance to the transformer as shown in the question above. The purpose of using StAX would be to avoid using `Document` at all, in order not to load all of a large XML structure into memory.

Comment: Thank you, but my Document is very large and I get an OOM on the transform method.  I've tried using StringBuilder and StringWriter instead of Document, but each of these requires a toString() at some point, which always gives an OOM.  I want to pass the String out on the request so as to open the XML file for download.  I can't even make a ZIP without doing a toString() to get the bytes.  Perhaps I should open my own question...

Comment: Why do you need to transform into a string? Can't you use a `FileWriter` and stream to disk, or an `OutputStreamWriter` and write to the HTTP response's output stream (if this is part of an API)? If you want to make a ZIP on the fly, one approach is to use `PipedInputStream`  and `PipedOutputStream` together with a helper thread. If you want code samples, please open your own question and add a comment here with a link, and I'll try to answer there instead.

Comment: Another option for making a ZIP on the fly is to transform to a `StreamResult` wrapping the ZIP output stream.

Comment: I'm working on something written a long time ago to output a string.  I'll try changing it to OutputStreamWriter, that sounds very promising, thanks.  If I need the ZIP help I'll start a new question.  Thanks again for taking the time.

Comment: Happy to help! :-)

Comment: I solved it by writing the XML lines directly to a PrintWriter allocated to the ServletResponse.  Thanks!